# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (Bybit API)

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python script with Bybit API (cryptocurrency). https://github.com/bybit-exchange/api-connectors/tree/master/official-http/python
I installed the package as suggested. But whenI first run this, it says: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I saw this is a very common error but could not figure out why in my specific case this is happening.

```
import bybit
client = bybit.bybit(test=True, api_key="***", api_secret="***")
```

Comment: Is your script called `bybit.py`? This [issue](https://github.com/bybit-exchange/api-connectors/issues/68)

Comment: Did you hack my computer? :D yes it was the issue... Thank you...